# Sort typescript array by alphabets first and numbers next using Intl.Compare

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to sort an array of objects based on their values.

**Given Input** `let arr = ['4-5', 'null-4', '7-null', '1-2']`

**Expected Output** `['null-4', '1-2', '4-5','7-null']`

I tried to use `string.localCompare()` along with `value.split('-')`, but it seems to slow down the execution. Then I tried to use `Intl.Compare`, but the result I'm getting is `['null-4','7-null', '1-2', '4-5']`.

I there any way I can get expected output using `Intl.Compare`

Answer (score 0):

Run `arr = arr.map(s => s.replaceAll('null', '0'))` befor sorting the array and see if this solves your problem.

You get your Output because `null - 4 == null` and `7 - null == null`